# AttributeError: 'Graph' object has no attribute 'dfs'

Tags: python, graph, artificial-intelligence

I have below python code to build knn graph but I have an error:

> AttributeError: 'Graph' object has no attribute 'dfs'.

It seems that the nx.Graph() has no node attribute but I don't know what should I replace with that.

```
import networkx as nx


def dfs(self,graph, node, visited):
    if node not in visited:
        visited.append(node)
        for n in graph[node]:
            self.dfs(graph,n, visited)
    return visited

def BFS(self, s):
    visited = [False] * (len(self.nodes))
    queue = []
    queue.append(s)
    visited[len(queue)] = True
    while queue:
        s = queue.pop(0)
        print (s, end = " ")
        co=len(queue)
        for i in self.adj[s]:
            co+=1
            print(visited[co])
            if visited[co] == False:
                queue.append(i)
                visited[co] = True

                
DW=nx.DiGraph()
DW.add_nodes_from(['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N',
'O','P','Q','R','S','T'])
DW.add_edge('A','B')
DW.add_edge('A','E')
DW.add_edge('B','F')
DW.add_edge('E','I')
DW.add_edge('F','J')
DW.add_edge('I','M')
DW.add_edge('M','Q')
DW.add_edge('M','N')
DW.add_edge('J','N')
DW.add_edge('N','R')
DW.add_edge('O','S')
DW.add_edge('O','P')
DW.add_edge('F','G')
DW.add_edge('G','K')
DW.add_edge('K','O')
DW.add_edge('G','H')
DW.add_edge('K','L')
DW.add_edge('C','D')
DW.add_edge('C','G')
DW.add_edge('P','T')
D =nx.Graph()
nx.draw(DW,with_labels=True)
visited = D.dfs(DW,'A', [])
print(visited)
```

Comment: Why the AI tag?

Comment: because this code for the AI lab work.

Answer (score 0):

The function `dsf` is not defined in any class, especially not in instance `D` of class `Graph`. That is the root cause of the issue you are seeing.

So you can either just use the function like so: (make sure to adjust all calls to `dsf` accordingly)

```
visited = dfs(DW,'A', [])
```

Or define everything in a class, e.g.:

```
class MyClass:
    def dfs(self,graph, node, visited):
[...]
```

and call the function with:

```
myclass = MyClass()
visited = myclass.dfs(DW,'A', [])
```